# Installing W3SVC on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010, iis

I'm preparing a new Exchange Server 2010 install on Windows Server 2008 R2. I've already installed the Remote Server Administration Tools and its IIS dependencies, although the Exchange Server Setup keeps failing and reporting that the W3SVC service is not installed.

What roles or features do I have to install on the server to get the W3SVC installed and running for the Exchange Server Setup?

Comment: can you post the exact error?  if not a screen shot then a verbatim copy of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install Exchange, there are lots of prerequisites and you need to follow a very specific procedure. Exchange is a complex application. :)

W3SVC is definitely part of the IIS role, but instead of just trying to tackle each error message one at a time, why not start off on the right foot.

Taken from Technet, here are the prerequisites for installing Exchange 2010 on Windows 2008 R2: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb691354.aspx#WS08R2 (Expand the section on 2008 R2.) Notice that there are various .NET frameworks and such that need to be installed first as well, and a lot of other IIS role services besides just the ones needed for RSAT.

Now once you have *all* those prereqs sorted out, try following the rest of this walkthrough here: 
http://www.enterprisenetworkingplanet.com/datacenter/Installing-Exchange-2010-Step-by-Step-3877601.htm

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Exchange Server Role(s) you plan to install, a number of role services must be installed. For your particular scenario, follow the link below and expand the specific section for Windows Server 2008 R2:

[Exchange 2010 Prerequisites](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb691354.aspx)